# SSDT Unit Test T4 template availability

Tags: templates, t4, sql-server-data-tools

I want to update the SSDT Unit Test template to wrap a transaction around each unit test using the information from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851217(v=vs.103).aspx to add this capability.

Are the T4 templates for SSDT Unit Testing available?  If so, where can I find them? Or is there another template mechanism used for SSDT Unit Tests?

Answer (score 0):

The file location varies by Visual Studio version, the 2015 files are in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\SQL Server\1033\SqlUnitTest.zip